# MongoError: Unknown modifier: $pushAll in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having an issue when saving a model fails with **mongo error: MongoError: Unknown modifier: $pushAll**.

I have one array field `subDomains` in my schema and which will get saved as default with subdomain as like follows.

```
 // already Domain instance get availble 
 Domain.subDomains.push({'name': 'default' , 'role': 'xyz', ...});

 // save domain with default fileds
 Domain.save()
```

System Info as like as follows:

```
         ➜  ~ node --version
          v9.4.0
          ➜  ~ npm --version
          5.6.0
          ➜  ~ 
          ➜  ~ mongo --version
            MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
            git version: ......
            OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
            allocator: system
            modules: none
            build environment:
                distarch: x86_64
                target_arch: x86_64
          ➜  ~
```

Please help me to sort out this one.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `$pushAll` operator is no longer supported in Mongo 3.6.2 (or any newer versions from 3.6.x+).

You can do the following:

- add the [`usePushEach: true` option the Schema definition](https://medium.com/@stefanledin/how-to-solve-the-unknown-modifier-pushall-error-in-mongoose-d631489f85c0) as in:

  ```
  new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String
  }, {
    usePushEach: true
  });
  ```
- downgrade to Mongo 3.4.11(or any 3.4.x version)

Comment: Small addition; you might need to downgrade multiple times. i.e. from 4.0 to 3.6, then 3.6 to 3.4, running `db.adminCommand({setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6"})` etc. Info here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-downgrade-standalone/

Comment: saved my day! simple perfect solution

Answer (score 20):

Adding to the above answers with the following code to get you a clarity in implementing **concat** method. You don't need to downgrade MongoDB particularly.

Before resolving this issue, you need to keep in mind that **$pushAll** method has been deprecated for a long time so perhaps they get rid of it in version 3.5 and above.

But you can resolve this issue with the other alternative  — **concat** method.

My old code,

```
myArray.push(id); //breaks on DocumentDB with Mongo API because of $pushAll
```

has been replaced with,

```
myArray = myArray.concat([id]); //this uses $set so no problems
```

Even [Azure’s own MongoDB implementation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/documentdb-protocol-mongodb/) doesn’t support $pushAll.

Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion this is the best solution since "downgrading to 3.4" is just not possible in the long run, and "usePushEach: true" seems to be like "please please I would like to keep using this deprecated piece of code". If "push" is deprecated, let's use concat and go for it.

Answer (score 12):

In case anyone new stumbles on this, from [mongoose 5xx](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/History.md), support for `usePushEach: true` option in schema definition was removed

You should instead use `concat()` where you'd normally use push when appending objects.
In cases where `concat()` does not work (example where `$inc` is called either explicitly or implicitly) use `unshift()`.

Answer (score 9):

I am using "mongoose": "^4.12.1" and usage of .push was throwing the same error. 
Usage of `usePushEach` works for me. We can turn it on for all the schemaslike this :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.plugin(schema => { schema.options.usePushEach = true });
const Schema = mongoose.Schema; 
const SampleSchema = new Schema({
    attr1: type,
    attr2: type,
    attr2: type,
    attr4: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'ref_table_name'
    }] });
```

Answer (score 7):

Replacing `.push` with `.unshift` is the best way to deal with this error.
I hope this might save your day.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using > 3.6 It's not working.
But if you would make it work, you can use `$push` along with `$each` it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

use concat solve the problem

```
 var newArray=  Domain.subDomains.concat([{'name': 'default' , 'role': 'xyz'}]) 
      Domain.subDomains=newArray
      Domain.save()
```

Comment: `Domain.subDomains.push({'name': 'default' , 'role': 'xyz', ...})` --> `Domain.subDomains = Domain.subDomains.concat([{'name': 'default' , 'role': 'xyz'}])`

Answer (score 1):

Replace .push() with .unshift()

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Domain._doc.subDomains.push({'name': 'default' , 'role': 'xyz', ...});
```

this works for me